# Random contour in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

So I have written a bit of code to simply find the convex hull of a hand, however there is this weird contour/border that is drawn around the border of the window.
How could I get rid of this border because I am trying to do some stuff with the numpy array that is outputted but this weird border is messing it up.

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

hand = cv2.imread('blackHand.jpg')

grayHand = cv2.cvtColor(hand, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(grayHand, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hiearchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hull = [cv2.convexHull(c) for c in contours]

final = cv2.drawContours(hand, hull, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
for c in contours:

print(c)

cv2.imshow('Hand', hand)

plt.imshow(hand, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')

plt.show()

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output I am getting looks normal for example just arrays of coordinates, however one array looks off. This is the border I believe.

[[[   0    0]]

[[   0  999]]

[[1163  999]]

[[1163    0]]]

[Here is the image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlGva.png)

Comment: show the output you are getting. Please post the input image and the resulted image.

Comment: Instead of using THRESH_BINARY, I changed it to THRESH_BINARY_INV, it got rid of it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your image so that the hand is white and background is black before getting the contour. So invert your thresholded image.

```
threshold = 255 - threshold
```